# C++ man pages in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, manpage

In Ubuntu linux I can't get any man pages for C++ keywords.  Is there some kind of package I can install to fix this?

Comment: superset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293737/where-are-the-man-pages-for-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev glibc-doc
```

Look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/) too for STL.

Comment: The command given here only installs C documentation, not C++.

Comment: Any examples with `man` after that please?? I failed to find for e.g. `man std::sort` or `man printf`

Answer (score 6):

check out this project: https://github.com/Aitjcize/cppman
Which generates manpages from cplusplus.com

Answer (score 4):

The libstdc++6-4.4-doc will install the man pages for STL too, not only the HTML doc. The manpages-posix-dev package is also really good to have.

Comment: It's interesting that this exists, but the online documentation is *much* easier to use: http://www.cplusplus.com or http://en.cppreference.com.

Answer (score 1):

You must install manpages-dev package :

```
$ sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider installing libstdc++6-4.4-doc, which installs the full C++ library documentation in HTML format, generated from the doxygen comments (you can find it in `/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.4-doc/libstdc++/html/index.html`, and I think that scrollkeeper indexes it). Remember to install the updated package when the installed g++ version changes.