# Where are the man pages for C++?

Tags: c++, linux, documentation, manpage

Does documentation for C++ exist in Linux? I want something like the man pages of C.
For example, docs for string, stl, iostream, ifstream, etc.?

Comment: Are you looking for a resource *not* on the internet?

Comment: You can just search up "c++ <feature you want to know about>" Most of the time this will result in a page from cplusplus.com

Comment: If only he had asked a more specific question, we could have pointed him to lmgtfy...

Comment: Just yesterday I found myself wishing libstdc++ provided manpages rather than forcing me to use a web browser to find documentation.

Comment: @Don Branson, thanks! but, i can see many people that could answer perfectly...

Comment: To the commenters above, have you ever done development somewhere that you had difficult or impossible access to the internet? Imagine that your only access is 25 to 75 steps away, on a machine shared by other people that use it throughout the day. And this is the only place that you can access the internet. No wifi or cell phone is available. And no modifications to the network are possible.

Comment: For other readers, you can clone this [repo](https://github.com/jeaye/stdman) then `./configure` and `make install` on your system. It will install documentation from cppreference.com available via your `man` command ie. `man std::queue`. Quite handy.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you use the "normal" libstdc++ shipped with g++, its documentation is available online [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/).

Most Linux distributions make it also available offline as a particular package; for Debian-derived distros, for example, it's `libstdc++-6-<version>-doc` (e.g. on my Ubuntu machine I have `libstdc++-6-4.4-doc` installed). In general the documentation will be put somewhere like `/usr/share/doc/libstdc++-6-4.4-doc`.

This about *implementation-specific* documentation; for compiler-agnostic docs, instead, many sites on the Internet provide reference documentation for the standard library.

One of the most referenced is nowadays [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com), that is actively maintained, tends to be very faithful to the standard and shows well the differences between the various standard versions; it can be a bit intimidating to newbies, though.

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) historically was one of the most used (especially as it is very "liked" by search engines), but was known to contain several errors or incorrect simplifications; I don't know if it got any better in these last years.

Also, [the C++ library section on msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bstk3k5.aspx) has got much better in the recent years in separating what are the Microsoft-specific details from what the standard dictates.

Finally, if you want precision up to the paranoia, the ultimate normative document is [the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/), that is [sold from ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38110), [ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=BS+ISO/IEC+14882:2003) and [BSI](http://shop.bsigroup.com/en/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030116778) (for a quite high price); there are however several drafts available for free, which are more than good enough for "casual use".

Comment: Thank you! It was a perfect answer to my doubt... I was searching it for a long time, but i couldnt find any answer like this...

Comment: IMO the best compiler-agnostic reference is http://en.cppreference.com/w/ it is mostly accurate, and it shows whether any given feature is C++03 or C++11

Comment: @FabioFracassi Yes, and in november 2014 the offline version of the documentation at cppreference.com was added to Ubuntu Vivid: `apt-get install cppreference-doc-en-html`.

Comment: IMHO this is a good resource too https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman

Comment: There's also a set of C++ man pages that can be copied from OpenSolaris, but they're incomplete to say the least.

Answer (score 42):

In Ubuntu, after installing `libstdc++-6-x.x-doc`, these docs are available via `man`, examples(libstdc++-4.8-doc)

```
man std::list
man std::weak_ptr
man std::ios_base
```

To get a list of these entries, use

```
apropos -r '^std' | vi -
```

This command gets all man entries beginning with `std` and sends them to `vi`.

==========

**Update**: as of libstdc++-4.8-doc, the prefix is `std::` instead of `std_`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu 12.04. I.e. I installed this package, but your example commands don't give the manual pages.

Comment: @Ruslan I have updated my answer, the prefix changed to `std::` instead of `std_`

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04, using the `man std::list` syntax.

Answer (score 14):

cppman is a C++ manpage formatter available [on Github](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman).

On request, it generates manpages from cplusplus.com, and it is quite good at it. Your manpage viewer will be cppman instead of man, though, and you still need to be online.

Comment: You can now cache all of them for off-line viewing. It takes approx 20 minutes.

Comment: Cppman has an option (-m true) to export its documents to man.

Comment: And the command for offline caching, after the [installation1](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman/wiki/Installing-from-Ubuntu-PPA) or [installation2](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman#installation) is simply `cppman -c`

Answer (score 8):

Install the man pages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-doc
```

Comment: Assuming your distribution uses apt for package management.

Comment: Just for the sake of precision, these are not manpages, but HTML docs (put in `/usr/share/doc/libstdc++4.4-doc`).

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard library is documented at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/. Your implementation might bring it's own documentation. For example libstdc++ from the GNU Compiler Collection is documented at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/. Look into the source distribution of the specific library to find out if and where the documentation is.

Comment: Unfortunately, cplusplus.com is really outdated in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu an offline copy of the excellent documentation at http://cppreference.com is available in the packages [cppreference-doc-en-html](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cppreference-doc-en-html&searchon=names) (HTML) and [cppreference-doc-en-qch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cppreference-doc-en-qch&searchon=names) (Qt Help format).

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install cppreference-doc-en-html
```

Comment: *Not available as of Nov 24, 2016.

Comment: I installed `cppreference-doc-en-html` in Ubuntu, but how should I use it? Doing `man fputs` will open Linux Programmer's Manual and not cppreference documentation. In other words, where are cppreference docs stored?

Comment: @Sergio `dpkg -L cppreference-doc-en-html` will tell you the contents of the package.

Comment: @zwets Thank you! That solved the problem now I can access the documentation.

Comment: How do you access them in linux ?

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL 6 the package `libstdc++-docs` installs documentation in `/usr/share/doc` AND man pages:

`sudo yum install -y libstdc++-docs`

now I can:
`man std::string`

for example.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pay close attention to the version of your compiler; on recent linux distributions you're likely using g++ v4.3, or maybe v4.4, but some of the newer C++0x features are in g++ v4.5, so depending on the features you are playing with, you may run into issues on that front.