# How do you man cpp functions?

Tags: c++, linux, manpage

For example,how do you `man std::sort`?

My tries seems not on the right track.

**UPDATE**

`yum install libstdc++-docs` gives me  `No package libstdc++-docs available`

Comment: Google seem to say it should work the way you're doing it, provided you have the appropriate libstdc++ man pages installed.

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/) might help.

Comment: This might be distribution-specific. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y ,it's `CentOS release 5.5 (Final)`

Comment: `firefox http://www.google.com/search?q=std+sort` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the man pages for C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293737/where-are-the-man-pages-for-c)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, c++ functions are not included by default in man pages in any linux distribution. You have to use manually install them with :

```
yum install man-pages libstdc++-docs
```

Comment: @Space That's something new ;) Thanks. fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have man pages installed?

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev glibc-doc
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-doc
```

[Where are the man pages for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293737/58737)

Whatever you are doing should work if man pages are installed properly. [see here](http://jrharshath.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/where-are-man-pages-installed-in-ubuntu/)

Installing these packages for your distro won't be very difficult. :-)

Comment: Then you will have to download it and install manually from [here](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/libstdc++/doxygen/)

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html). Its not about libstdc++ but for any general package in linux.

Comment: I've familiar with the `configure && make && make install` thing.But in the page you provided,I downloaded the man pages,there's no `configure` scripts at all.

Answer (score -1):

First install the man pages as the others suggested.

Then a nice workflow with man is to use the -k arg, since -k is "search for".

So if we take a general example with the classical c function printf (since it is ambiguous)

```
$ man -k printf
...
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (1posix)      - write formatted output
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
printf (3posix)      - print formatted output
...
```

Then you can see the c functions as 3 and 3posix and the shell command as 1 and 1posix. And since we would like to read about the c function.

```
$ man 3posix printf
```

So in your case you should be able to search for your lib and then read it. (if it is installed that is).

Hope it clarifies some part of your question.

Comment: Ok, then you can ignore this answer.