# How to install man pages for C++11

Tags: linux, c++11, ubuntu, manpage

I know the man pages for C++ are installed with `libstdc++6-<version>-doc`, but when I'm looking for a function like `stoull` there is no man page. Even `apropos` does not find anything.

Man pages are available online: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoull/ or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul but I would like to have them offline.

Is there a way to install the man pages under GNU/Linux?

--Corbie

Comment: Newest `libstdc++` should do the trick for C++11. For example, you can do `man std::shared_ptr` which is avalaible since C++11. However, the function `stoull` is not included for some unknown reasons - you can verify here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the man pages for C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293737/where-are-the-man-pages-for-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found this: https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman

Since **cppman** is no longer supported under Ubuntu/apt it has to be installed via

```
pip3 install cppman
```

and if you want to have the man pages offline you may cache them by

```
cppman -c
```

make sure to have your preferred source selected. [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com) should be default.