# How to find to which library a function belongs in c++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, libraries

for example if I were to write `std::cout<<"Hello\n";` without having `#include<iostream>`, what can I do just from the terminal to find out that I need iostream?

Comment: Unless someone wrote manpages for C++, you can't. You'd normally look it up in a reference, like http://cppreference.com

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Netbeans, you can press CTRL and click the text `cout` and it will take you to either it's declaration or its definition (at least that works on windows). Otherwise you should use cppreference.com, which is a great resource.

Comment: @Cubic: You think someone hasn't?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896547/103167  And then `apropos` or `man -k` commands should help find the right page.

Answer (score 0):

iostream is a library which contains command cout. cout will not work without it. so it will be an error of compiler which says why this command does not work. if you are using  gcc or g++ compiler it will write the error in your terminal. I hope this info was useful